# Initial lines of code block are not formatted, cannot submit post

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

I cannot get my question accepted, because when I paste a code block, the first lines (import statements, class def.) are omitted from the code block, as is the final }.   Also, weirdly. the * is omitted from the import statements.

OK, to be specific, here's the code block:

import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestRegex {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a pattern to match two integers, comma-delimited
    Pattern intCommaInt = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+),\\s*(\\d+)$");

    String str = "123,456";
    Matcher match = intCommaInt.matcher(str);

    System.out.println("\n" + match.group(1) + "   " + match.group(2));
}
```

}

Well it gets accepted here on the meta-site!   But, as you can see, the import statements and class def. and final closing curly brace are omitted from the code block - even though I selected the whole block - and the import stsements have lost their asterisks and been concatenated on a single line.   Here's the original, without `code`formatting:
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestRegex {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a pattern to match two integers, comma-delimited
    Pattern intCommaInt = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+),\\s*(\\d+)$");

    String str = "123,456";
    Matcher match = intCommaInt.matcher(str);

    System.out.println("\n" + match.group(1) + "   " + match.group(2));
}
```

}

OK here's a screenshot:[image: Page showing incorrect formatting]

Comment: The answer below covers the *main* issue, but the next question is, what *else* does your question contain?  Perhaps you're hitting a quality filter for the question being mostly code.

Comment: The \* has been interpreted as a formatting code for italics. I don't know what you thought formatting of the code meant.

Answer (score 4):

For code to appear in a code block, it must be indented 4 (or more) spaces.

If you look at your screenshot, you can see that code you pasted hasn't been properly indented at all.

- The first line has only been indented 3 spaces.
- The following two lines (and closing bracket) have not been indented at all.

The only reason that some of the code appears properly formatted is because part of what you pasted in was already indented 4 spaces due to being inside the `TestRegex` class.

[image]

To properly format it here, you have to select all the code you pasted, then press CTRL-K to indent it by 4 (additional) spaces.  The leading lines will then end up indented by 4 spaces, and the code inside the class will be indented by 8 spaces (the 4 it was originally indented by before you copied it, plus the additional 4 that CTRL-K added).

*FYI, the first line often is problematic, because it is often selected at the start of its code, instead of the start (first column) of the line.*

Answer (score 3):

To format code, indent the entire codeblock 4 spaces, **or** highlight it and click the "Code Sample" button on the top menu.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a pattern to match two integers, comma-delimited
        Pattern intCommaInt = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+),\\s*(\\d+)$");

        String str = "123,456";
        Matcher match = intCommaInt.matcher(str);

        System.out.println("\n" + match.group(1) + "   " + match.group(2));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried indenting, and the button, and Ctrl+k.
As I said the beginning and end get left off in the code block and the system then says my question cannot be accepted due to incorrect code formatting.

Comment: @John Could you perhaps try to edit your question with a screenshot of what is going wrong?

Comment: @John I can't seem to reproduce that on Chrome v47.0.2526.106 and I'm afraid I don't have any other browsers available to test atm. Maybe someone else can chip in.

Comment: @John, it would be helpful to know what browser/OS you are using now, so that we can accurately reproduce the error.