# Cannot format code

Tags: support, code-formatting

Whenever I paste my code, it's really pain in the neck.
I googled it to format it correctly, nothing works.

[Initial lines of code block are not formatted, cannot submit post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315231/initial-lines-of-code-block-are-not-formatted-cannot-submit-post)

[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

[How should I use Outlook to send code snippets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151152/how-should-i-use-outlook-to-send-code-snippets)

I've tried every possible ways to format the code correctly.
But as you see the following image, can't format it correctly.

I paste my code and click code sample button, or command + K ( using mac ). 
I also tried type four spaces and the posted code and tried others.
But nothing works. What have done wrong?

public class FileWrite {
        ...
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Lock otherLock = new ReentrantLock();
        ...

```
    void writeToFile() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // write to a file, aaa.txt similar with the following two lines.
            FileOutputStream fot = new FileOutputStream(new File("aaa.txt"), false);
            fot.write(data);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            ...
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    void inCaller() throws Exception {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            for (...) {
                otherLock.lock();
                try {
                        writeToFile();
                        return;
                    }
                } finally {
                    otherLock.unlock();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

}

```
    class CallerClass implements Runnable {
    private FileWrite fr;

    public CallerClass(FileWrite fr) {
        this.fr = fr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        fr.lock.lock();
        try {
            for ( ... )) {
                    ...
                fr.writeToFile();
                ...
            }
            ...
            }
        } finally {
            fr.lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: That code looks like it just needs to be indented 4 spaces.  Instead of taking a picture, if you actually replicate the problem in your question then anybody can click on "Edit" and see what you've tried.

Comment: ...or, find a post that has correctly formatted code and click "edit" to see how it was done.

Comment: And what do you mean with "nothing works". What result do you get? Still unformatted code? Error message?

Comment: That programmers cannot figure out how to select a block of code and type Ctrl+K is a never-ending source of amusement for me.

Comment: "*I've tried every possible ways to format the code correctly*". 
That's verifiably false. You haven't tried the correct way yet.

Answer (score 1):

Indent your code four spaces *before* pasting it into the question, and it will indent properly.

As an example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a pattern to match two integers, comma-delimited
        Pattern intCommaInt = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+),\\s*(\\d+)$");

        String str = "123,456";
        Matcher match = intCommaInt.matcher(str);

        System.out.println("\n" + match.group(1) + "   " + match.group(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that manually indenting isn't necessary. Just highlight the code and press `ctrl+k`, or highlight and press the `{}` button above the editor.